Unable to write data in file
I have data stored in one file - delimiter tab
{'id': '123', 'name': 'pečnostní informační služba'}
When I am trying to  read the data  and write data in 2nd file using python code but getting error
  with open(output_file, 'w') as f_output, open(input_file,encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as f_input:

        reader = csv.DictReader(f_input,delimiter='\t')
        fieldnames =  reader.fieldnames


        writer = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()

        for row in reader:
            print(row)
    
            writer.writerow(row)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python_Projects\Python_extra_code\csv_example.py", line 180, in <module>
    writer.writerow(row)
  File "C:\Dev\Python3.11\Lib\csv.py", line 154, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Dev\Python3.11\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u010d' in position 69: character maps to <undefined>


your output file uses 'cp1252' encoding. This encoding doesn't have unicode character č which you are trying to save. You can replicate the error by running this two lines:
text = '\u010d' 
text.encode('cp1252')

Try fixing this error by saving in utf-8 encoding:
with open(output_file, 'w',encoding='utf-8') as f_output:
    text = '\u010d' 
    f_output.write(text)

Or by allowing to ignore errors while saving badly decoded characters:
with open(output_file, 'w',encoding='cp1252', errors='ignore') as f_output:
    text = '\u010d' 
    f_output.write(text)


in both cases it should solve issue with converting bad chars. "UTF-8" should be the best format.

its resolved. accepting answer
